# Modify all values of a column PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to PySpark dataframes and used to work with RDDs before. I have a dataframe like this:

```
date        path
2017-01-01  /A/B/C/D
2017-01-01  /X
2017-01-01  /X/Y
```

And want to convert to the following:

```
date        path
2017-01-01  /A/B
2017-01-01  /X
2017-01-01  /X/Y
```

Basically to get rid of everything after the third `/` including it. So before with RDD I used to have the following:

```
from urllib import quote_plus

path_levels = df['path'].split('/')
filtered_path_levels = []
for _level in range(min(df_size, 3)):
    # Take only the top 2 levels of path
    filtered_path_levels.append(quote_plus(path_levels[_level]))

df['path'] = '/'.join(map(str, filtered_path_levels))
```

Things with pyspark are more complicated I would say. Here is what I have got so far:

```
path_levels = split(results_df['path'], '/')
filtered_path_levels = []
for _level in range(size(df_size, 3)):
    # Take only the top 2 levels of path
    filtered_path_levels.append(quote_plus(path_levels[_level]))

df['path'] = '/'.join(map(str, filtered_path_levels))
```

which is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Any help regrading this would be much appreciated. Let me know if this need more information/explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, lit, concat

split_col = split(df['path'], '/')
df = df.withColumn('l1_path', split_col.getItem(1))
df = df.withColumn('l2_path', split_col.getItem(2))
df = df.withColumn('path', concat(col('l1_path'), lit('/'), col('l2_path')))
df = df.drop('l1_path', 'l2_path')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

@udf
def quote_string_(path, size):
    if path:
        return "/".join(quote_plus(x) for x in path.split("/")[:size])

df.withColumn("foo", quote_string_("path", lit(2)))
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with udf is that it turns out to be very slow specially when dealing with very large data (TB in my case), so I decided to stick to other pyspark functions.